# Need help completing unfinished implementation of FFT bit reversal in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, fft

I'm taking over some code meant to run an FFT algorithm on images. The FFT implementation is incomplete and contains the following segment:

```
public Complex[] doFFT(Complex[] data, int size){
    Complex[] temp = new Complex[size];

    int j=0;
    int k;
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        temp[i] = data[j];
        while((j>=k) && (k>0)){
            k /=2;
        }
        j+=k;
    }

...

}
```

Where `data` is the 1D input array of Complex numbers, size is the length of `data` and `temp` is the output array after all of the FFT algorithm is completed. This particular block is supposed the 'bit reversal' step of the algorithm.

I've never seen bit reversal done this way. Obviously `k` is not initialized and I have no idea what the author was trying to do with it. I've tried tracing it with `k = 0`, `k = size`, and `k = size/2` and none seems to give the output I'm looking for.

Can anyone decipher what the author was trying to do here or suggest a better implementation?

Comment: Did you notice that j is always equal to "0" so you are doing k>0 and k<=0 which actually makes no sense

Comment: For the first round that's true, but `j = j+k` every round of the loop. The question here is what to initialize `k` to to make it so a) `data[j]` stays in bounds, and b) this outputs proper bit reversal.

Comment: Why not write it the way you know how to do it or use a different one? Plenty of free FFTs available.

Comment: I don't think I have much of a choice. After tracing more of the code it looks like the author was trying to rewrite and integrate with ImageJ's implementation of the FHT algorithm and gave up halfway through.